# Some games seem to be not available yet in Hong Kong Playstation Store?

Tags: psn, ps4

Just bought one PS4 last weekend and it works great. I'm registered in HK PSN network. However I don't see some titles supposedly already out, such as *Apotheon* and *Hand of Fate*. Is it a normal behavior that they lag behind NA/EU releases quite considerably? They should all just be eventually available, right? I mean there is no reason for HK government to censor/block any games that are already out in other places and no reason for Sony not to sell them. (Some people say Sony HK is independent of Sony Asia in region classification?) Or is it actually just that they're not available online yet but are already available in disk?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know about HK specifically, but differences in release dates are pretty common in gaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video games, and more generally all products, worldwide are subject to a lot of variability on when, and even if, they are available. Video games in particular have issues with localization, software laws, trade restrictions, censorship, ratings, distribution, region-locking, and a host of other things. Even, and sometimes especially, when doing digital distribution over something like PSN.

Basically, the long and short of it is, outside of official announcements, there is no telling if or when something is going to be available in your region. If you are curious about a particular game or games, I would reach out to either the developers or Sony to see if they have an official statement on the matter. Other than that, it is simply a matter of waiting until it is available.

Answer (score 0):

Well I searched the web, and the results pointed out that that game is going to launch in HK quite soon.